# JDBC component schema test: CFGFWK-64216: Data source ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied connection test failed

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

My JDBC connection test is failing in oracle middleware configuration. I have install oracle form and reports and successfully created repository and configuration.
I update the existing domain template with config.cmd in oracle_home/oracle_common/common/bin folder. In Oracle middleware fusion configuration at 6 out of 10 (jDBC test) this shows up:

> Component Schema=LocalSvcTbl Schema Driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
> URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE User=DEV_STB
> Password=**************************************************** SQL
> Test=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
>
> CFGFWK-64213: Test Successful! CFGFWK-64213: JDBC connection test was
> successful. CFGFWK-64213: No action required.
>
> Component Schema=WLS Schema Driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
> URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE User=DEV_WLS_RUNTIME
> Password=**************************************************** SQL
> Test=ISVALID
>
> CFGFWK-64213: Test Successful! CFGFWK-64213: JDBC connection test was
> successful. CFGFWK-64213: No action required.
>
> Component Schema=OPSS Audit Schema Driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
> URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE User=DEV_IAU_APPEND
> Password=**************************************************** SQL
> Test=ISVALID
>
> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
>
> CFGFWK-64210: Test Failed! CFGFWK-64210: JDBC connection test failed.
> CFGFWK-64210: Check logs for more information.
>
> Component Schema=OPSS Audit Viewer Schema
> Driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
> URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE User=DEV_IAU_VIEWER
> Password=**************************************************** SQL
> Test=select 1 from schema_version_registry where owner=(select user
> from dual) and mr_type='IAU_VIEWER' and version like '12.2.1%'
>
> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
>
> CFGFWK-64210: Test Failed! CFGFWK-64210: JDBC connection test failed.
> CFGFWK-64210: Check logs for more information.
>
> Component Schema=OPSS Schema Driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
> URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE User=DEV_OPSS
> Password=**************************************************** SQL
> Test=select 1 from schema_version_registry where owner=(select user
> from dual) and mr_type='OPSS' and version like '12.2.1%'
>
> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
>
> CFGFWK-64210: Test Failed! CFGFWK-64210: JDBC connection test failed.
> CFGFWK-64210: Check logs for more information.

I have created weblogic jdbc generic data resources. I am new in oracle and I am trying to learn oracle forms and reports. Many things I can't understand.

Comment: `ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied` Use the correct username and password.

Comment: Which user name and password should I provide

Comment: The user for the Oracle database schema you want to connect to and their corresponding password.

Comment: It says ,CFGFWK-64217: JDBC data source validations failed. I used the XE as database service and used the password of schema that I set when creating repository and configuration.

Comment: The first connection is to the `DEV_STB` user, the second to `DEV_WLS_RUNTIME`, the third to `DEV_IAU_APPEND`, the fourth to `DEV_IAU_VIEWER` and the fifth to `DEV_OPSS`. The third through fifth fail - use the correct passwords for those users.

Comment: I needed to uninstall to the 21c oracle database , installed 19c database, create databse in toad. Then it's working fine.