# Forms builder logon denied

Tags: oracle

I have configured the TNS but my form builder connection says invalid user name and password. I am using the same username and password that I have used in the exact database.
ORA-01017 : invalid username/password ; logon denied

This is my tns.ora file in fmwconfig folder

tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\Oracle\db_home\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

```
LISTENER_ORCLDB =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1522))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCLDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcldb)
    )
  )
```

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71112187/1509264

Comment: No, it was for configuration wizard. Now my forms and reports are working fine except the database connection. I am looking for the answer. previously none of your answer worked for me.

Comment: Oracle is too dumb to lie about ORA-01017.  Either the username or the password you are supplying is incorrect for the database you are hitting.  Perhaps case-sensitivity of passwords is coming into play. Perhaps you are not connecting to the database you think you are.   BTW, why are you running your listener on the non-default port of 1521?

Comment: I used sys username and forms taking system username and it worked ,thank you